# Click only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some react code. There I have button with onClick function. When I click on button, score increases by one point.

I want to make it so that when I click on the button, it adds one point to score, after one click it can’t add one points anymore

How to do it?

```js
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      result: 2,
      score: 0
    };
    
    this.getRes = this.getRes.bind(this);
  }
  
 
  
  getRes() {
    if (this.state.result == 2) {
      this.setState({score: this.state.score+1})
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div style={{paddingTop: 10}}>
        <p>
        <button>1</button>
        <button onClick={this.getRes}>{this.state.result}</button>
        </p>
        
        <p>{this.state.score}</p>
        
        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [disable semantic Button in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43836669/disable-semantic-button-in-react)

Answer (score 0):

Try to re organize your code in this way by introducing a disabled property to disable your button after first click

```
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      disabled: false,
      result:2,
      score: 0
    };

    this.getRes = this.getRes.bind(this);
  }



  getRes() {
   this.setState({disabled: true, result:this.state.result+1})

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <div style={{paddingTop: 10}}>
        <p>
        <button>1</button>
        <button onClick={this.getRes} disabled={this.state.disabled}>{this.state.result}</button>
        </p>

        <p>{this.state.score}</p>

        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but You can disabled your button when score is 1 and more:

```
<button onClick={this.getRes} disabled={this.state.score >= 1}>
  {this.state.result}
</button>
```

or check it in your method:

```
getRes() {
  if (this.state.score >= 1) {
    return;
  }

  if (this.state.result == 2) {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + 1
    })
  }
}
```

or add extra field in your state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      disabled: false,
      result: 2,
      score: 0,
      clicked: false,
    };

    this.getRes = this.getRes.bind(this);
  }



  getRes() {
    this.setState({
      result: this.state.result + 1,
      clicked: true,
    })

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ paddingTop: 10 }}>
          <p>
            <button>1</button>
            <button onClick={this.getRes} disabled={this.state.clicked}> 
              {this.state.result}
            </button>
          </p>

          <p>{this.state.score}</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add in the state is_click:true
as this

```
this.state = {
      result: 2,
      score: 0,
is_click:true,

    };
  getRes() {
    this.setState({
      result: this.state.result + 1,
      clicked: true,
is_click:false

    })

  }
```

once the user onclick setstate false and add to button disabled={this.state.is_click}

```
<button onClick={this.getRes} disabled={this.state.is_click}>{this.state.result}</button>
```